# python UTF-8 can't handle (ñ) and (ö)

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, ascii

I am reading a line from a file, and then copy that line to another file.

This is the code to read content of the file

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".ttl"):
        with open(file) as fileTTL:
            lines = fileTTL.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                writeRDFToFile(line)
```

and for each line, i call the **writeRDFToFile** function, which is:

```
def writeRDFToFile(rdf):
    f = open('joined.ttl','w')
    try:
        rdf = rdf.encode('UTF-8')
        f.write(rdf) # python will convert \n to os.linesep
    except Exception as e:
        print "exception happened " + rdf
        print e
    f.close()
```

I got this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position XXX: ordinal not in range(128)
```

on this value:

> Luis_Buñuel
>   Lasse_Hallström

But as you see, I already trying to encode it with UTF-8, so why the error is ascii from the first place ?

Thanks

Comment: You're right, my comment made no sense >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you have here is the *input*, not the *output* (hard to be sure without the stack trace)

Your file reading (effectively doing `open(file).readlines()`) is reading this file as a list of **string** objects, not unicode which `encode('UTF-8)` requires (it is trying some automagic instead, I believe, but failing as the input is not ASCII).

Try removing the `rdf = rdf.encode('UTF-8')` completely.

Comment: removing the line completely removed the exception but in the output file, i just got the last line of the last file, i am supposed to have all the lines from all the files in the output file.

Comment: it is like every time i am writing **above** the current content, not **append** to the current content. could you help please ?

Comment: Well that's another problem.

Either use mode `'a'` (`open('joined.ttl', 'a')`) or, much better, open the output file once (e.g. just after your `with open(file) as fileTTL` with another similar `with` statement)